# Uploading images using Rails or Android app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, cloudinary

I'm using Rails to create an API only app, storing data in MongoDB Atlas, and an Android app to make requests.
One of my models has an image attribute and its value it's gonna be a link from Cloudinary, I was reading its documentation and found that they have SDKs for both Rails and Android. I don't know if it's better to use Android to upload the image, and then send the link to Rails, or use Rails to accept an image from the app and handle all the image uploading.

Comment: Either of those options should work, depending on your requirements. There are details on the Cloudinary site explaining the main difference, which is between the upload being 'signed' (server side, uses your API secret for authentication), or 'unsigned' (from the client side, using a pre-defined set of upload options from your account settings): https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#unsigned_upload

High level, the main differences are that sending the uploads from Android to Rails has more setup and complexity and will be slightly slower, but gives you more control